# e.target.files - что такое files

Tags: javascript, jquery, файлы

При работе с изображением используется такой код

```
function changeImage(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var fr = new FileReader(); 
    fr.onloadend = function() {
        document.getElementById('img').src = fr.result;
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);                         
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что "files" - это тип инпута `<input type="files">` https://api.jquery.com/file-selector/#file1 ? Если так, где можно найти официальную доку, где описано это использование? Гугл выдает только ссылки на форумы, но должен же быть первоисточник. "files" в доке по JQ не ищется, только похожие слова, например ":file" в других доках так же.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае это [свойство `files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) у `<input type="file">`.

В нем содержатся выбранные файлы.